# Give a proof or a counter-example. A function f is analytic in an open set implies f being bounded there.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Complete question: Give a proof or a counter-example. If $B^º$ is an open set of C and $f: B^º\rightarrow C$ is an analytic function, then f is bounded in $B^º$.

My attempt:

If $f$ is bounded, then $|f(z)|\leq M, M \in N$, $\forall z \in B^º$. Let $g(z)=e^z$, entire in C. Then, there exists an $M \in N$, such that, $|e^z|\leq M, \forall z \in B^º$.
$\rightarrow ln(|e^z|)\leq ln(M) \Rightarrow z\leq ln(M)$, but, as $B^º\subset C$ is any open set, we could choose it as $B^º\cup \{ z_0 \} $, where $z_0 > M$ which would led to a contradiction. Thus, $f$ being analytic does not imply being bounded in an open set.

Is this correct?

Comment: what does "limited" mean?

Comment: ops, I've changed the word, it should be "bounded" instead of "limited".

Comment: Why not just look at $1/(1-z)$ in the open unit disc?

Comment: I tried with that function. Is the following argument correct?
Let $f(z)=\frac {1}{(1-z)}$ analytic in the open set $B^º(0,1)$. 
$\lim_{x\to 1^+} f(z)=-\infty$ and $lim_{x\to 1^-} f(z)=+\infty$, thus, we could not find a M such that, $|f(z)|\leq M, \forall z \in B^º$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is not correct but it becomes correct if you just choose $z$ to be real. For complex $z$ it is not true that $\ln(|e^{z}|)=z$ and the inequality $z \leq \ln M$ does not make sense. Besides, you can take the open set $B^{0}$ to be $\mathbb C$ in your argument.

Comment: I just thought something about it right now. When I add the $z_0$ to set $B^º$, wouldn't this change M again, so that the inequality $z\leq ln(M)$ would still hold?

Comment: @LinconRibeiro To give a counter example you can take the open set $B^{0}$ to be $\mathbb C$. Any real number $z_o >M$ can b e used in your argument.